# Getting Debugging option checkerror when i upload my app in galaxy store

Tags: java, android, android-studio, samsung-galaxy

whenever i try to upload my app in galaxy store my app always gets rejected in pre-Reviews and the issue it shows is Title :- Debug option check     Test Result :- The debuggable attribute in the manifest (android:debuggable="true") SHOULD NOT be true.

Although developers can set true while developing applications for debugging purpose, those applicaitons SHOULD NOT be released with the attribute because users can debug the applications even without access to its source code.

but the debuggable attribute is false in the android manifestation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.bigbeast.calculator">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:debuggable="false"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Calculator"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedDebugMode">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to build release app differently and debug app differently

In debug we build by going to Build => Build Bundle / APK(s) => Build APK(s)

For release app we need to create by going to => Build => Generate Signed Bundle / APK(s)

I recommend following this tutorial https://youtu.be/0ntRRLPL5Lg